# How to filter a nested/lower subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Say if I have a result like this:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b722d06c23b5f2bd0329a41"),
        "name" : "test",
        "item" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b722d07c23b5f2bd0329a53"),
            "display_name" : "",
            "image" : "http://via.placeholder.com/700x500/ffffff/000000/?text=No%20Image&",
            "is_private" : true,
            "details" : [
                {
                    "is_private" : false,
                    "type" : "text",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5b722d06c23b5f2bd0329a44"),
                    "title" : "Name",
                    "content" : "",
                    "order" : 0
                },
                {
                    "is_private" : false,
                    "type" : "text",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5b722d06c23b5f2bd0329a43"),
                    "title" : "Price",
                    "content" : "",
                    "order" : 1
                },
                {
                    "is_private" : false,
                    "type" : "text",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5b722d06c23b5f2bd0329a42"),
                    "title" : "Company",
                    "content" : "",
                    "order" : 2
                }
            ],
            "tags" : [ ],
            "__v" : 0
        }
    }
```

and I want to filter by `item.details.is_private`, how should I do this? I want to return all properties of `item` but filter out any `item.details.is_private` if it is `true`

I am currently projecting it as:

```
{
    "$project": {
        name: 1,
        item: 1
    }
}
```

but am not sure how to implement `$filter` in this setting

Comment: Try `{     "$addFields": {       "item.details": {         "$filter": {           "input": "$item.details",           "cond": {             "$eq": [               "$$this.is_private",               true             ]           }         }       }     }   }`

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3985214/2683814

Comment: @Veeram don't think it's a duplicate because mine is 1 level down, so I can't just use a straight up `$filter` like Anthony did. I might need to do some kind of `$unwind` into a `$redact` back into a `$concatArray` but I'm not sure if that's the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [**`$addsFields`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) with [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)  aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "item.details": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$item.details",
        "as": "detail",
        "cond": {
          "$eq": [ "$$detail.is_private", true ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: this only returns `item.details` though, I also need the rest of the `item` stuff

Comment: isn't there a better way to do this? Since, if the document updates with additional fields in the future, then I'll have to account for every single unique field

Comment: Don't ever take nested documents in your model to keep better performance and it's the best way to do work with mongodb...

Comment: cool, seems to work. I'm guessing that `$addFields` is just overiding the original `details` then

Comment: @A.Lau precisly