# mongoose query or aggregation to remove certain subdocument fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Say I have the following document

Item

```
{
    details: [
            {
                "title": "Name",
                "content": "",
                "is_private": false,
                "order": 0,
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "title": "Price",
                "content": "",
                "is_private": true,
                "order": 1,
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "title": "Company",
                "content": "",
                "is_private": false,
                "order": 2,
                "type": "text"
            }
        ],
}
```

If I wanted to return only the subdocument fields `details` which have `is_private === false`, is there a way to do it in mongoose's query or do I need to use aggregation?

e.g.

```
ItemModel
    .find()
    // something should go here to remove
```

Comment: not familiar with mongoose but can give you native mongo aggregation query

Comment: @dsharew I wouldn't mind that either, in case someone doesn't answer.

Comment: You have to use `$filter` aggregation here... As you asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833317/how-to-filter-a-nested-lower-subdocument... Even if you use `$elemMatch` then it will only return  the first matched document with `is_private === false` not all matching ones

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet yeah, was mainly just curious if there was a query for this in mongoose.

Comment: Well aggregation is also a query... So instead you should ask for "can it be done using find query"... Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

In case you wanted to do it using native aggregation query:

```
db.getCollection('item').aggregate([
   {
      $unwind:"$details"
   },
   {
      $match:{
         "details.is_private":true
      }
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:"$_id",
         details:{
            $push:"$details"
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d0edb6cfaf771ecf675f0"),
    "details" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "Price",
            "content" : "",
            "is_private" : true,
            "order" : 1.0,
            "type" : "text"
        }
    ]
}
```